# How to compare strings in wix ExePackage?

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix3.7, wix-extension

```
<ExePackage InstallCommand='/q /action=UPGRADE /HIDECONSOLE /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS=1 /INSTANCENAME=ABC' InstallCondition="SqlVersion32 &lt; v10.50.1600.1 AND SqlEdition32 = 'Express Edition'"/>
```

I am using the above code. In install condition I want to check if `SqlEdition32` (its value is provided by a registry search) is Express edition but I am having error saying:

> Error 0x8007000d: Failed to parse condition "SqlVersion32 <
>   v10.50.1600.1 AND SqlEdition32='Express Edition'". Unexpected
>   character at position 46.

Position 46 is where I am comparing `SqlEdition32` string variable to string 'Express Edition' 
I want to know how to compare strings in WiX?

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes around strings, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

1. You can replace double quotes with single quote and vice versa, so
   you will have something like this:

> ```
> InstallCondition='SqlVersion32
>     &lt; v10.50.1600.1 AND SqlEdition32 = "Express Edition"'
> ```

2. Or replace single quote **'** with ***&quot ;***, you will get:

> ```
> InstallCondition="SqlVersion32 &lt; v10.50.1600.1 AND
>     SqlEdition32 = &quot;Express Edition&quot;"
> ```